Forum group categories not following sort_order after server migration
The site I manage recently did a migration to a larger server after we both outgrew our previous one and as well it was at the end of its life.
Since then, I've noticed that our forum categories no longer sort by the sort_order chosen in their SQL table, but instead follow the ID# for each category.
Code in question:
        $cat_loop = @mysqli_query($mysqli_link, "
            SELECT
                forum.*,
                P.game_name,
                P.admin,
                M.title
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    C.id,
                    C.name,
                    (SELECT COUNT(M.id) FROM messageboard M WHERE cat=C.id AND replyto=0) AS num_posts,
                    (SELECT M.author FROM messageboard M WHERE M.cat=C.id ORDER BY IF(M.bump > M.date, M.bump, M.date) DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_poster,
                    (SELECT IF(M.replyto = 0, M.id, M.replyto) FROM messageboard M WHERE M.cat=C.id ORDER BY IF(M.bump > M.date, M.bump, M.date) DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_topic,
                    (SELECT IF(M.bump > M.date, M.bump, M.date) FROM messageboard M WHERE cat=C.id ORDER BY IF(M.bump > M.date, M.bump, M.date) DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_post_date
                FROM
                    messageboard_cats C
                WHERE
                    C.group='{$group['id']}'
                ORDER BY
                    C.sort_order
                ) AS forum

What the corresponding category table looks like in, using group 1 as an example:
screenshot of the categories table in the database
From what I can tell of the code (I'm far from an expert but can generally read it to have an idea of what it's meant to do), it looks correct, however instead of the sort order indicated in the image above, it's displaying as the following:
Official Announcements
Suggestions
Bug Reporting
Get a Breed Added
Community Announcements
Community Announcements is supposed come after Official Announcements, and did so correctly on our old server. Nothing was changed to the file during the migration.

You're sorting categories in the subquery, which doesn't mean at all that the results of the outermost query will be sorted that way.
Include the sort_order field in the subquery's SELECT, and then sort the results in the actual query that's getting the results from it:
SELECT
    forum.*,
    P.game_name,
    P.admin,
    M.title
FROM (
    SELECT
        C.id,
        C.name,
        C.sort_order # <- select the sorting column to be in the result set
        (SELECT COUNT(M.id) FROM messageboard M WHERE cat=C.id AND replyto=0) AS num_posts,
        (SELECT M.author FROM messageboard M WHERE M.cat=C.id ORDER BY IF(M.bump > M.date, M.bump, M.date) DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_poster,
        (SELECT IF(M.replyto = 0, M.id, M.replyto) FROM messageboard M WHERE M.cat=C.id ORDER BY IF(M.bump > M.date, M.bump, M.date) DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_topic,
        (SELECT IF(M.bump > M.date, M.bump, M.date) FROM messageboard M WHERE cat=C.id ORDER BY IF(M.bump > M.date, M.bump, M.date) DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_post_date
    FROM
        messageboard_cats C
    WHERE
        C.group='{$group['id']}' # <- no sorting here any more
    ) AS forum
ORDER BY forum.sort_order # <- do the sorting here

